# Onclick not working on dynamic rendering html

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna create a method to rendering a new button inside a div, and then add some click event on it. Here is my code:

```js
let create = () => {
    function abc() {
        alert("abc")
    }

    let t = document.querySelectorAll(".here")[0];
    t.innerHTML = "<button onclick='abc()'>click me 2</button>";
}

document.querySelector("#clickme").addEventListener("click", () => {
    create()
})
```

```html
<button id="clickme">
    click me
</button>

<div class="here">
    a
</div>
```

Click the "click me 2", why my `abc()` is not defined?

Comment: `abc` is scoped within `create`.

Comment: ok i got this, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Click the "click me 2", why my abc() is not defined?

Because attribute event handlers look for the method in global scope, and your `abc` method is not in global scope, it is in the scope of `create`

Comment: Please, add the code snippet that works as required (for better understanding what you mean)

Comment: @AndrewEvt the question did not ask for working code, it asked why the existing code does not work. This is the answer to _that question_.

Answer (score 2):

The function call inside `onclick` attribute (and other attribute even handlers) are run in global scope so it has no access to this `abc` function.

So `onclick='abc()'` is equivalent to `onclick='window.abc()'`

You have two ways in order to make it work:

1- `window.abc = abc`:

```js
let create = () => {
    function abc() {
        alert("abc")
    }

    window.abc = abc;

    let t = document.querySelectorAll(".here")[0];
    t.innerHTML = "<button onclick='abc()'>click me 2</button>";
}
```

Which is not really recommended.

2- Use `addEventListener` which is the best option here:

```js
let create = () => {
    function abc() {
        alert("abc")
    }

    let t = document.querySelectorAll(".here")[0];
    t.innerHTML = "<button id='clickme2'>click me 2</button>";

    const clickme2 = document.querySelector('#clickme2');
    clickme2.addEventListener('click', abc);
}
```